# Android Google Maps API v2: get my bearing location

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I would like to force the camera to behave like you are using navigation, it means when you rotate 90° left, the camera does the same thing.

I have a Google Map where my location (as a blue dot) is shown.

```
mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
```

When I am moving, blue dot is with an arrow which shows my current bearing. I would like to get this bearing.

I am getting my current location using *FusedLocationApi*:

```
 currentLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
```

Code below is animating camera to current location, **but** without the bearing. I can add the bearing, but I don't know the value.

```
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        LatLng latLng = new LatLng( location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude() );
        mGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
        mGoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));

    }
```

Do you know how to get the current location direction? I was unable to find any proper information about that. I would greatly appreciate any help you can give me.

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you can try to use `getOrientation(R, orientation)` (and adjust for true north) to `get the device rotation`. You can refer to [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html#getOrientation(float[],%20float[])).

Also, use the `CameraPosition` class [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/CameraPosition.html) to adjust camera position.

EDIT: I even found better solution. Use `getBearing()` method in [Location](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html) class.

```
if (location.hasBearing()) {
            CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                .target(latLng)             // Sets the center of the map to current location
                .zoom(15)                   // Sets the zoom
                .bearing(location.getBearing()) // Sets the orientation of the camera to east
                .tilt(0)                   // Sets the tilt of the camera to 0 degrees
                .build();                   // Creates a CameraPosition from the builder
            mGoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
        }
```