# Move the marker along the directions on map

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, bearing

I have a Googlemap and added a marker on it.What I want is, the marker should move as the user moves ,for example if the user takes a left turn then the marker icon should also rotate to left.I know this can be achieved by setting the **bearing** value to the marker.For getting the bearing value ,I used the **bearingTo()** function ,but it always returns zero.Can anyone please explain why the bearing value returned is always zero ? OR is there any other way to rotate the marker icon ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28951974/android-google-maps-api-v2-get-my-bearing-location

Comment: @Neha, please refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37048987/4748607)

Comment: @NiravBhavsar thanks alot !!! You saved my day

Comment: @Neha, Welcome!!!